# Different number of lines per column in the table in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

In WinForms, I want to present tabular data where each column has a different number of rows. The problem is that the number of rows for each column is fixed and the user may not be able to edit below. How do I fix this? Can I configure any table control in WinForms or can I use any other free control? Coloring of individual cells is also a requirement in this case.

Example:

- Cells without data can not be edited and are grayed out
- Cells with xxx and yyy is any numeric value
- Cells with yyy has different background color than other

  ```
             | col 1 | col 2 | col 3
  channel 1  | xxx   | xxx   | xxx
  channel 2  | xxx   | xxx   | yyy
  channel 3  | xxx   | xxx   | xxx
  ...
  channel 48 | yyy   |       | xxx
  channel 49 | xxx   |       | xxx
  channel 50 |       |       | yyy
  channel 51 |       |       | xxx
  channel 52 |       |       |
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your case 100% (can you provide a diagram perhaps?), but you can solve what I think I'm hearing with Sourcegrid (open source)

http://sourcegrid.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would try creating a separate table for each column in the top level table.  You would probably have to create a datasource for each of these tables.